# The back, home and menu buttons are not lit

Tags: screen, alcatel-one-touch-idol-s

but they work. How can I make them backlit again?
I have an ALCATEL ONETOUCH IDOL 2plus
Thanks and regards

Comment: @RahulGopi Please don't post answers as comments.

Answer (score 0):

Please check through these steps.

1. Just reboot and see whether it functions or not.
2. Goto recovery mode and clear cache data and check.
3. Do a factory reset and check.

After all these if no response, it may be a hardware issue, take the device to manufacturer's service center and check.